# Android emulator connecting to local mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, localhost, emulation

The emulator won't start because an error is found in my mainactivity. when I debug the code, an exception occurs at line:

> HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Can anyone help me? This is the first time I have attempted to connect an android emulator to a localhost mysql database. The following is my onCreate method in the mainactivity class.

---

### MAIN   ACTIVITY

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    JSONArray jArray = null;

    String result = null;

    StringBuilder sb = null;

    InputStream is = null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //http post
    try{
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

         //Why to use 10.0.2.2
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/Appli/androidAccess.php");
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();
         }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
    //convert response to string
    try{
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
           sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

           String line="0";
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                          sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                  Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }

    String name;
    try{
          jArray = new JSONArray(result);
          JSONObject json_data=null;
          for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                 json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 name=json_data.getString("NAME");//here "Name" is the column name in database
             }
          }
          catch(JSONException e1){
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Data Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } catch (ParseException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
```

Here is my php file in the htdocs

---

### ANDROIDACCESS.PHP

> ```
> <?php
> mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
> mysql_select_db("appli");
> $sql=mysql_query("select fName from userTest where id = 1");
> while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
> $output[]=$row;
> print(json_encode($output));// this will print the output in json
> mysql_close();
> ?>
> ```

---

### LOGCAT

> 12-29 20:02:54.850: E/log_tag(845): Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   12-29 20:02:54.850: E/log_tag(845): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
>   12-29 20:02:54.860: D/AndroidRuntime(845): Shutting down VM
>   12-29 20:02:54.860: W/dalvikvm(845): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aecba8)
>   12-29 20:02:54.890: E/AndroidRuntime(845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-29 20:02:54.890: E/AndroidRuntime(845): Process: com.example.loginapp, PID: 845
>   12-29 20:02:54.890: E/AndroidRuntime(845): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginapp/com.example.loginapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Are you able to access your url in emulators browser?????

Comment: The emulator won't even start.

Comment: I asked whether you can access the url in emulators BROWSER

Comment: You're not accessing a mysql database. You're TRYING to access a PHP script which accesses mysql on your behalf. MySQL is pretty much irrelevant for this problem. You're not even able to do the http connection in the first place.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I can. It displays a JSON with the fName.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your HTTP request...Check whether you have right permissions added in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And Check your URL from your emulator or from the device... if you are not able to access it, Find the right url....

Open command prompt->type ipconfig-> Get IPV4 address.... something like 192.xx...

[image]

So your URL is "http://192.xx.xx.xx/Appli/androidAccess.php"

To access your local host from your android emulator Use the ip address given in ipconfig.

Comment: I have added that permission into my manifest, I'm using a mac so I added the inet address, I still receive an error and the emulator won't start. Using the inet address: http://192.xxx.x.xx/appli/androidaccess.php in the emulator's browser displays the JSON with the fName.